# How to check if a string contains whitespace?

Tags: string, rust

How do I check if a string contains any whitespace in Rust?

For example, these should all return true:

- `"Hello, world!"`
- `"Hello\n"`
- `"This\tis\ta\ttab"`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can pass [`char::is_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace) to [`.contains()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains):

```rust
assert!("Hello, world!".contains(char::is_whitespace));
assert!("Hello\n".contains(char::is_whitespace));
assert!("This\tis\ta\ttab".contains(char::is_whitespace));
```

`char::is_whitespace` returns true if the character has the Unicode `White_Space` property.

Alternatively, you can use [`char::is_ascii_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_ascii_whitespace) if you only want to match ASCII whitespace (space, horizontal tab, newline, form feed, or carriage return):

```rust
// This has a non-breaking space, which is not ASCII.
let string = "Hello,\u{A0}Rust!\n";

// Thus, it's *not* ASCII whitespace
assert!(!string.contains(char::is_ascii_whitespace));
// but it *is* Unicode whitespace.
assert!(string.contains(char::is_whitespace));
```

Comment: If you're only checking for ASCII whitespace, it may be significantly faster to go byte-by-byte: `string.as_bytes().iter().any(u8::is_ascii_whitespace)`

Comment: Why would that be significantly faster?

Comment: Calling `.contains(...)` with a closure that takes `char` means iterating over all the Unicode code points, including the multibyte ones, converting each multi-byte sequence to a `char` and calling `is_ascii_whitespace` on it. A lot of that can be optimized away, and it is, but it makes things easier on the compiler when you just ask it to find all the bytes that are one of a limited set. [You can compare the generated assembly code](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Gaa6GK); `u8::is_ascii_whitespace` is about a quarter the size of `char::is_ascii_whitespace` (that's *with* full optimizations).

Comment: When you're iterating over bytes looking for ASCII characters, you don't have to worry about multibyte sequences, because bytes in the range `0..=127` never appear in them. So that code can be written much more simply. In theory the compiler could know this and optimize with that assumption, but in fact it does not.

Answer (score 3):

As someone mentioned, if you do not need to deal with Unicode, it will be faster
to just explicitly name the characters you care about:

```
fn main() {
   let a = vec!["false", "true space", "true newline\n", "true\ttab"];
   let a2: &[char] = &[' ', '\n', '\t'];

   for s in a.iter() {
      let b = s.contains(a2);
      println!("{}", b);
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not think this will be faster. What they meant is it will likely be faster to call `.contains()` on a byte array if you're only looking for ASCII whitespace: `string.as_bytes().iter().any(u8::is_ascii_whitespace)`